# Swagger Open API 3.0.1: How to define an array of object for the response example

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

Defining a swagger definition for an API specification using Open API 3.0.1. However,the response example GoodResponse defined here is not rendered. The syntax seems to be valid though. Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated

```
paths:
  /java/api/play:
    post:
      tags:
        - some-controller
      operationId: someOperation
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/xml:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/HarryKartType'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/GoodResponse'
components:
  schemas:
    GoodResponse:
      required:
        - goodstatusCode
        - goodresponseMessage
      type: object
      properties:
        goodstatusCode:
          type: integer
          example: 200
        goodresponseMessage:
          type: array
          example:
            - position: 1
              horseName: "TIMETOBELUCKY"
            - position: 2
              horseName: "HERCULES BOKO"
            - position: 3
              horseName: "CARGO DOOR"
          items:
             $ref: '#/components/schemas/GoodResponseMessage'
             
    GoodResponseMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        position:
                type: integer
                example: 1
        horseName:
                type: string
                example: "TIMETOBELUCKY"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define $ref within the `schema` , not within `items`
Try this:

```
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/GoodResponse'
```